# Jade and Node.js : no action when click on submit on post method WHAT TO DO NOW

Tags: node.js, pug

[APP.js Snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HbuZ9.png)

[contact.jade snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Wpuu.png)

[Snapshot of Page on Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lhInl.png)

When I click on Submit button nothing happens control stays on same page.
I am realy stuck at this point, any help will be apprecaited.

Thank you

Comment: Do not post screenshots of code.

Comment: You can improve your question by using the code formatting tools provided, either by using four spaces at the beginning of each line or the "code snippet" feature.

Answer (score 1):

You need to ensure your button is inside the form tag by indenting it.

```
form
  button
```

This translates to the HTML

```
<form>
  <button></button>
</form>
```

which allows the button to know which form it should submit. 
As your code stands now it is

```
<form></form>
<button></button>
```

For which the button does not have a parent form.

(You similarly need to this for your `input`'s... otherwise they won't be sent to the endpoint.)